# Retrieve all user details from Microsoft Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to retrieve all users from AD using Microsoft Graph APIs.

**https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users**

But this is returning only some top n rows from the whole users list.

I guess its using some pagination there. But didn't find how to specify page number or those details as a parameter within the query.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ms Graph cant show all users in the same page as it may cause threshold issues if the user count is too high.

you need to use paging to achieve this i.e., to get all the users you can achieve it with the help of `@odata.nextLink` please refer [Ms Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/paging) for more details.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I had no idea @odata.nextLink was the key.